# What is the difference between "su -" and "bash -l"?

Tags: linux, shell

What's the difference between `su -` and `bash -l`?

I have this problem:

```
:/etc/profile.d # su -
Cannot open display "default display"
Directory: /root
Thu Nov 28 11:23:57 CET 2013
```

Now I try to find out why this message occurs.

```
:~ # logout
:/etc/profile.d # bash -x -l
+ test -f /proc/mounts
+ case "`/bin/ls -l /proc/$$/exe`" in
++ /bin/ls -l /proc/17167/exe
+ is=bash
+ read -t 1 a r
...
```

In the second output I have no sign of the "cannot open display" message.
So what's the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first command logs you in as root; the option `-` means, from the `su Manpage`:

> -l, --login
>              Provide an environment similar to what the user would expect had the user logged in directly.

The second command, `bash -l`, does **not** log you in as root. It is true that the `-l` option means (again from the `bash Manpage`):

> -l        Make bash act as if it had been invoked as a login shell

However, this refers to a `different user`, in this case yourself instead of root. Thus, the `bash -l` command maintains the MIT magic cookie which allows control of your X session, while the `su -c` is not capable of doing that and, since you do not have the appropriate MIT magic cookie, you cannot take control of the X session.

If you want to get around this problem, insert this statement

```
  export XAUTHORITY=/home/your_name/.Xauthority
```

in the file /root/.bashrc, and you will be able to open GUIs as root even when you are su'ing instead of using a proper login shell.

Comment: Sure, `su` and `bash` are not the same thing ;-) I now figured out what was happening by adding `set -x` to /etc/profile. It turned out a script that belonged in /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d/ was present in /etc/profile.d/

Comment: BTW the source of the message was a command that was in one of bash's startup sripts (bashrc or profile) whereas it should have been in xinitrc, duh.